# Bootstrap font is different in react

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I want to make login page using bootstrap and react. I use the following [style](https://startbootstrap.com/snippets/login/) from official page. I added these all bootstrap and css files in index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">

    <link href="all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="autorization.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

But result is another than when I open throug a regular html page. The font is different.

This is how it should be:

[image]

And this is what I have:

[image]

I don't understand why, because I didn't change css files...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be the issue with `index.js` file. There you remove importing `index.css` line.

Remove this line in `index.js` file.

```
import './index.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

You maybe load another CSS file after bootstrap rewrites CSS style rules from BS or bootstrap CSS file is not loaded, please check it in the console or in the browser which style from which file is applied like a first

Answer (score 0):

You can dominate with important;

example:

font-family: 'Lilita One'!important;